# Mutable iterators in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, optimization

While benchmarking my application, I noticed accessing arrays items by index in relatively expensive in Python, making `for v in lst: v` signicantly faster than `for i in range(len(lst): lst[i]`:

```
from array import array

a_ = array('f', range(1000))

def f1():
    a = a_
    acc = 0
    for v in a:
        acc += v

    return acc

def f2():
    a = a_
    acc = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        acc += a[i]

    return acc

from dis import dis
from timeit import timeit
for f in f1,f2:
    dis(f)
    print(timeit(f, number=20000))
    print()
```

Producing:

```
  9           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (a_)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

 10           6 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (acc)

 11          12 SETUP_LOOP              24 (to 39)
             15 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             18 GET_ITER
        >>   19 FOR_ITER                16 (to 38)
             22 STORE_FAST               2 (v)

 12          25 LOAD_FAST                1 (acc)
             28 LOAD_FAST                2 (v)
             31 INPLACE_ADD
             32 STORE_FAST               1 (acc)
             35 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           19
        >>   38 POP_BLOCK

 14     >>   39 LOAD_FAST                1 (acc)
             42 RETURN_VALUE
0.6036834940023255

 17           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (a_)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

 18           6 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (acc)

 19          12 SETUP_LOOP              40 (to 55)
             15 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (range)
             18 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (len)
             21 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             24 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             27 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             30 GET_ITER
        >>   31 FOR_ITER                20 (to 54)
             34 STORE_FAST               2 (i)

 20          37 LOAD_FAST                1 (acc)
             40 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             43 LOAD_FAST                2 (i)
             46 BINARY_SUBSCR
             47 INPLACE_ADD
             48 STORE_FAST               1 (acc)
             51 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           31
        >>   54 POP_BLOCK

 22     >>   55 LOAD_FAST                1 (acc)
             58 RETURN_VALUE
1.0093544629999087
```

The core of the loop differs only in the presence of the extra `LOAD_FAST` `BINARY_SUBSCR` opcodes when using indexed access. However, this suffices for the iterator-based solution to be about 40% faster than using indexed access.

Unfortunately, in this form, iterators are only usable for *reading* the input array. Is there a way to use a "fast" iterator to change *in place* the item of an array, or do I have to stick to the "slow" indexed access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For full loops, you can split the difference with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), using indexed access for setting a value, and the name for reading it:

```
for i, value in enumerate(mysequence):
    mysequence[i] = do_stuff_with(value)
```

You can't avoid the indexed reassignment in a general loop structure though; Python has no equivalent to C++ reference semantics where assignment changes the value referred to, rather than rebinding the name.

That said, if the work is simple enough, a `list` comprehension avoids the need for an index, by building the new `list` and wholesale replacing the old one:

```
mysequence[:] = [do_stuff_with(value) for value in mysequence]
```

Assigning to the complete slice of `mysequence` ensures it's modified in place, so other references to it see the change. You can leave off the `[:]` if you don't want that behavior (you'll rebind to a new `list` with no other references to it).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ShadowRanger. In fact, I noticed array/list allocation and copy is cheap in Python since this is done with native code. And actually, even for arrays with thousands of values, I have better performances rebuilding a new array from a list comprehension rather than trying to modify the data in place. This is just a waste of memory, so I wanted to be sure I didn't miss something equivalent to C++ reference semantic.

Comment: I've [compared your solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59093296/2363712) with a couple of other. Copy from  list comprehention is clearly the fastest.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some timeit results for the different methods:

```
     #for v in a       #for i in range(len(a))  #for i,v in enumerate(a)
[[0.47590930000296794,   0.8639191000038409,    0.7616558000008808],
 [0.43640120000054594,   0.832395199999155,     0.7896779000002425],
 [0.44416509999427944,   0.8366088000038872,    0.7590674000020954]]
```

Note that using numpy arrays is very fast, but only if you build the array inside numpy and only use the native numpy functions:

```
import numpy as np
def f4():
    N = 1000
    vect = np.arange(float(N))
    return np.sum(vect)
```

timeit gives:

```
[0.09995190000336152
 0.10408379999716999
 0.09926139999879524]
```

Attempting to modify a numpy array by explicit indexing seems to be give no advantage, however. Also copying any native Python structure into a numpy array is expensive.

Comment: Thanks for the data. Indeed, Numpy would be a solution since it makes extensive use of native functions to speedup calculations. Unfortunately, in my particular case today, I have to work only with what's provided in a standard Python-3.5 installation.

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to @ShadowRunner's answer, I've done some extra benchmarking to compare the different solutions to modify an array in place.

Even for relatively large arrays, it's cheaper to build a new array from a comprehension list, then overwriting the original array, rather than trying to modify in its turn the individual items of the array.

```
import itertools
from functools import reduce
import operator
from array import array

a_ = array('f', range(100000))
b_ = array('f', range(100000))

def f1():
    a = a_
    b = b_
    for i,v in enumerate(a):
        b[i] = v*2

def f2():
    a = a_
    b = b_
    for i in range(len(a)):
        b[i] = a[i]*2

def f3():
    a = a_
    b = b_
    getter = a.__getitem__
    setter = b.__setitem__
    for i in range(len(a)):
        setter(i, getter(i)*2)

def f4():
    a = a_
    b = b_
    b[:] = array('f', [v*2 for v in a])

from dis import dis
from timeit import timeit

for f in f1,f2,f3,f4:
    dis(f)
    print(timeit(f, number=2000))
    print()
```

Result:

```
 10           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (a_)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

 11           6 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (b_)
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (b)

 12          12 SETUP_LOOP              40 (to 55)
             15 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (enumerate)
             18 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             21 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             24 GET_ITER
        >>   25 FOR_ITER                26 (to 54)
             28 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
             31 STORE_FAST               2 (i)
             34 STORE_FAST               3 (v)

 13          37 LOAD_FAST                3 (v)
             40 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
             43 BINARY_MULTIPLY
             44 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
             47 LOAD_FAST                2 (i)
             50 STORE_SUBSCR
             51 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           25
        >>   54 POP_BLOCK
        >>   55 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             58 RETURN_VALUE
24.717656177999743

 16           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (a_)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

 17           6 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (b_)
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (b)

 18          12 SETUP_LOOP              44 (to 59)
             15 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (range)
             18 LOAD_GLOBAL              3 (len)
             21 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             24 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             27 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             30 GET_ITER
        >>   31 FOR_ITER                24 (to 58)
             34 STORE_FAST               2 (i)

 19          37 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             40 LOAD_FAST                2 (i)
             43 BINARY_SUBSCR
             44 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
             47 BINARY_MULTIPLY
             48 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
             51 LOAD_FAST                2 (i)
             54 STORE_SUBSCR
             55 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           31
        >>   58 POP_BLOCK
        >>   59 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             62 RETURN_VALUE
25.86994492100348

 22           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (a_)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

 23           6 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (b_)
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (b)

 24          12 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             15 LOAD_ATTR                2 (__getitem__)
             18 STORE_FAST               2 (getter)

 25          21 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
             24 LOAD_ATTR                3 (__setitem__)
             27 STORE_FAST               3 (setter)

 26          30 SETUP_LOOP              49 (to 82)
             33 LOAD_GLOBAL              4 (range)
             36 LOAD_GLOBAL              5 (len)
             39 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             42 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             45 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             48 GET_ITER
        >>   49 FOR_ITER                29 (to 81)
             52 STORE_FAST               4 (i)

 27          55 LOAD_FAST                3 (setter)
             58 LOAD_FAST                4 (i)
             61 LOAD_FAST                2 (getter)
             64 LOAD_FAST                4 (i)
             67 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             70 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
             73 BINARY_MULTIPLY
             74 CALL_FUNCTION            2 (2 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             77 POP_TOP
             78 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           49
        >>   81 POP_BLOCK
        >>   82 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             85 RETURN_VALUE
42.435717200998624

 30           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (a_)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

 31           6 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (b_)
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (b)

 32          12 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (array)
             15 LOAD_CONST               1 ('f')
             18 LOAD_CONST               2 (<code object <listcomp> at 0x7fab3b1e9ae0, file "t.py", line 32>)
             21 LOAD_CONST               3 ('f4.<locals>.<listcomp>')
             24 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
             27 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             30 GET_ITER
             31 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             34 CALL_FUNCTION            2 (2 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             37 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
             40 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             43 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             46 BUILD_SLICE              2
             49 STORE_SUBSCR
             50 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             53 RETURN_VALUE
19.328940125000372
```